# ParallelSubmit and WaitNext: check if a job is done before calling WaitNext

Tags: parallelization, asynchronous-processing

Say I process something with ParallelSubmit:

```
LaunchKernels[]

job = ParallelSubmit[1 + 2]

Parallel`Developer`QueueRun[]
```

Then, I will use `WaitNext[{job}]` later to retrieve the result of this job, but: I do not want to call the function `WaitNext`, which blocks the main kernel, before I know that there is at least one finished job.

Unfortunately, these things will not work:

```
Parallel`Developer`DoneQ[job] (* === False *)
(* will not evaluate to True before the job is done AND retrieved by WaitNext[] *)

Parallel`Developer`ProcessState[job] (* === Parallel`Developer`queued *)
(* same here, will not change to unqueued before the job is done AND retrieved by WaitNext[] *)
```

Is there any way to find out if a job has finished before calling `WaitNext[]`?

Comment: I think you need to use `QueueRun[]` before `DoneQ` will know that the job has finished.  The first time you evaluate  `QueueRun[]`, the job will be submitted, but at this point it is not done yet.  Of course just a fraction of a second later is finishes running on the subkernel.  But the main kernel (where you use `DoneQ`) does not know this until we trigger a communication with another `QueueRun[]`.  Now `DoneQ[job]` is `True`.  Try submitting many jobs and looking at their status as they're displayed in blue, green, grey in the notebook.  The status changes only on `QueueRun[]` calls.

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer because this is all just guesses from some experimentation, usage message of `QueueRun` this doc topic: `ParallelTools/tutorial/ConcurrencyManagingParallelProcesses`.

Comment: Ha, excellent, it works! Indeed `QueueRun[]` does not only submit the job, it also receives the result, as stated in the documentation you mentioned. Thank you, looks like an exact answer to me. :)